# Content going past footer at bottom of page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been searching around, but I can't find much help.

I have my footer placed at the bottom of the page using the absolute positioning method:

```
footer{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  min-height: 100px;
  padding:{
    top: 10px;
    bottom: 10px;
  }
  border: {
    top: solid 2px #fff;
  }
}
```

When I try to get it to push to the bottom of the page regardless of page height I still get behavior like this:

[image]

I've tried putting body height at 100%, as well:

```
html, body{
  background-color: $background-color-primary;
  height: 100vh;
}

body{
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}
```

I do not want it to be fixed, as this is an undesireable behavior for the website, I just want to go all the way to the bottom regardless of the main content height.

Comment: Replace `height: 100vh;` by `min-height: 100vh;`.

Comment: In addition to `position:fixed` in the footer, you'll have to put the `margin-bottom` on it the last div above the `footer`

Comment: I don't want it fixed like that though, I want it pushed all the way to the bottom

Comment: @MarkHill do you want it at the bottom of the *screen* or the bottom of the _content_?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a little unclear how you want the footer to display...

**If you want the footer pinned to the bottom of the viewport**, then I would recommend using `position:fixed;` rather than `position:absolute;`.

Additionally, you will need to set a `margin-bottom` equal to the height of the footer so that the content from the page does not become hidden underneath the footer.

**If you want the footer beneath the content**, then make the following changes:

- Remove `position:absolute;` from the footer.
- Remove `height:100vh;` from `html` and `body`.
- Ensure the footer is `display:block;`.
- Ensure that the container for your main content does not have `position:absolute`, `position:fixed` nor `float`.
- Ensure that the HTML for your footer is placed beneath your content.

Comment: It should be noted that if he does this .. There will need to be a `margin-bottom` of the height of the footer on the last `div` above the footer -- so that the content isn't hidden by the footer when the user scrolls to the bottom of the page.  -- And that wasn't my downvote ..

Comment: np .. This in my opinion is the most viable solution anyway .. So +1 from me.

Comment: This isn't the solution that I"m after. I want it to get it to push all the way to the bottom of the page. Or if that would look bad, I would rather have the container where the images appear stop at the height of the footer from the bottom.

Comment: I initially downvoted because I thought the question was clearer, basically asking about a sticky footer. I removed my downvote as I realized the question was too unclear

Comment: @General_Twyckenham how could I clarify the question, what is missing?

Comment: @MarkHill my comment on your question above; namely, do you want the footer at the bottom of the **screen** or the bottom of the **content**?

Comment: @General_Twyckenham bottom of the content

Comment: @MarkHill Ok - I'd update your question to say that then, as it's clearer. Check this out for some methods to do this: https://css-tricks.com/couple-takes-sticky-footer/

Comment: @MarkHill Updated my answer to take into account both scenarios.